# boolean flag with multiple same records

Tags: mysql, database, boolean

What is the best solution for inserting/updating boolean values from my table.

Every week or month, the number of `point` can be changed, for example current Data:

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
| id | phone_id | tarrif_id | affiliate_id | point | active |
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
|  2 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   7.3 |      0 |
|  3 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   8.5 |      0 |
|  4 |        6 |         2 |            3 |  12.5 |      0 |
|  5 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   3.5 |      1 |
|  6 |       20 |         2 |            3 |  10.5 |      1 |
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
```

I would insert a new record with same `phone_id`, `tarrif_id` and `affiliate_id` with a new point and disable other records `active=0`.

New Points Changed, for example:

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
| id | phone_id | tarrif_id | affiliate_id | point | active |
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
|  2 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   7.3 |      0 |
|  3 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   8.5 |      0 |
|  4 |        6 |         2 |            3 |  12.5 |      0 |
|  5 |        6 |         2 |            3 |   3.5 |      0 |
|  6 |       20 |         2 |            3 |  10.5 |      0 |
|  7 |        6 |         2 |            3 |  20.2 |      1 |
|  8 |       20 |         2 |            3 |  33.7 |      1 |
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: What should the result set look like after this update can you please post a sample?

Comment: What does happen if the value of all columns is the same (e.g. you insert a point value that exists already for phone_id, tarrif_id and affiliate_id)?

Comment: Also the question sounds rather straight forward and I wonder what hinders you to just do it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @hakra Do you mean all columns is the same including the points value?  Well I could insert a now rows again... but I could add "AddedDate" field for historical records.. What do you think? Is there other way instead of using Boolean flag?

Comment: If you need to keep a record of the changes, I would suggest to add a date-field as well. You then could choose the latest, then you won't even need to look for something that is "active" as by design the latest is the active one.

Comment: @hakra That is a good suggestion but if I want to disable the latest one even its include date-field?

Comment: Well you would add a new entry with the active flag = 0. As it would enter a new entry, you would have a new date and the deactive one would be the latest. You should decide whether you want history or you want the last active one. Either you only store the last one, or you store each change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
-- 1. Disable other records
UPDATE point SET active = 0;

-- 2. Insert new rows
INSERT INTO point (phone_id, tarrif_id, affiliate_id, point, active)
SELECT phone_id, tarrif_id, affiliate_id, /* Your computation here */, 1
FROM point
GROUP BY phone_id, tarrif_id, affiliate_id
WHERE active = 0;
```

You will still need to know how to compute your new `point` values (20.2 and 33.7 in your example).

Comment: This will insert multiple repeating rows when executed the second, third, ... time.